# riscv-tools Setup requirements?

Tags: toolchain, riscv

I am interested in RISCV software tools, and have some
knowledge in linux and toolchain. I want to setup riscv-tools on my system
running in ubuntu 14.04 - 32 bit. I tried the steps given in github and the
build failed. Is there any basic requirement for this build.

Error log:

```
configure: WARNING: decimal float is not supported for this target, ignored
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'

../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'

In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'

../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'

../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'make[3]: *** [_enable_execute_stack.o] Error 1
make[3]: 
*** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [_lshrdi3.o] Error 1
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
make[3]: *** [_ashrdi3.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_muldi3.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_cmpdi2.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [__main.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_clear_cache.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'make[3]: *** [_negdi2.o] Error 1

../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
make[3]: *** [_ucmpdi2.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'make[3]: *** [_absvdi2.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_ashldi3.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_absvsi2.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'

../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'make[3]: *** [_addvdi3.o] Error 1

make[3]: *** [_trampoline.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
make[3]: *** [_addvsi3.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
make[5]: *** [_muldi3.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[5]: *** [_lshrdi3.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [_negdi2.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
make[5]: *** [_ashldi3.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
make[5]: *** [_cmpdi2.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [_ashrdi3.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [_clear_cache.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [_ucmpdi2.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [multi-do] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-multi] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [build-gcc-newlib] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2014 Oct 27, a 64-bit system is required to build the RISC-V toolchain.