# Errors when compiling riscv-gcc

Tags: gcc, riscv

I want to use the riscv-gcc. I got it from https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gcc but when i compiled it I got errors below

`../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:139:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'
In file included from ../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:57:0:
../../../../build-gcc-newlib-src/libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.h:138:1: error: no data type for mode 'TI'`

i don't know what's the problem and I have use this revision to build the FlexPRET project and the newest revision is not copatible with FlexPRET.

Comment: See the similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850477/riscv-gcc-for-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a 64-bit system to build riscv-gcc?

Switching to one may solve this problem: [riscv-tools Setup requirem​ents​?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581455/riscv-tools-setup-requirements)