# riscv-gcc for Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, riscv

I want to use riscv-gcc under Windows 7/8/10 32 or 64 bit. I downloaded source files from https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gcc
I tried to build riscv-gcc using MinGW many times and each time I get an error, then I've tried to remove the bug, but on the next build attempt I get another one((
Here is a small list :

1)

```
c:/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/hashtab.c: In function 'hash_pointer': 
c:/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/hashtab.c:202:24: error: 'intptr_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
   return (hashval_t) ((intptr_t)p >> 3);
```

2)

```
c:/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/hashtab.c:418:64: error: 'free' undeclared (first use in this function)
   return htab_create_alloc (size, hash_f, eq_f, del_f, calloc, free);
```

3)

```
:/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/fibheap.c:38:24: error: 'LONG_MIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define FIBHEAPKEY_MIN LONG_MIN
```

4)

```
c:/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/unlink-if-ordinary.c: In function 'unlink_if_ordinary':
c:/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/unlink-if-ordinary.c:65:15: error: storage size of 'st' isn't known
   struct stat st;
```

5)

```
up.c:gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS  -I. -I/c/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-co pat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  /c/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/sort.c -o sort.o3
:3: warningcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS  -I. -I/c/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc +-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  /c/mingw/build/riscv-gcc/binutils-2.21.1/libiberty/xstrerror.c -o xstrerror.og
 implicit declaration of function 'strlen' [-Wimplicimake[3]: t*** [unlink-if-ordinary.o] Error 1
```

I'm not a "linux guy", I just want to have a Windows-compatible toolchain to use with RISC-V soft core in my FPGA projects.
Does anybody have riscv-gcc for Windows already? Many thanks!

I've completed some experiments and my conclusion is:
- if your only goal is using RISC-V (or MIPS) within an FPGA and you don't want to have any deal with Linux, the best solution is FPGArduino http://www.nxlab.fer.hr/fpgarduino/
I tested it with Xilinx Spartan-3AN Starter Kit and successfully ported it to custom Spartan-6 board.

Comment: This should not be different than compiling gcc on Windows. Please post any RISC-V specific issues you run into.

Comment: This seems a more recent version, https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain

Comment: Your problems might be related to what version of compiler you have. Output from `gcc -v` could help.

Comment: Good point! Do not use https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gcc. Use github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala, here is the output `$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32`

Comment: continued here `Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-`

Comment: and the last part. `gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)` Sorry for poor formatting

Comment: @user2548418, I have used `mingw` for the first time. As I see now, I have no RISC-V specific errors, but that software package was completely downloaded from RISC-V repository. I'll try to use your link, thanks!

Comment: @user2548418, @J.J.Hakala, there is the result of `riscv-gnu-toolchain` build attempt: `$ make
rm -rf src/gcc src/gcc.tmp
cp -a src/original-gcc src/gcc.tmp
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libgomp/testsuite/libgomp.graphite' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gfortran.dg/graphite'
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/config/locale/newlib' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/g++.dg/graphite'` To be continued

Comment: `cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/23_containers/multimap/debug/invalidation' to directory src/gcc.tmp/libjava/classpath/lib/gnu/xml/util'
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/24_iterators/front_insert_iterator/requirements' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/cris/torture'
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/25_algorithms/copy_if/requirements' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/nds32'` To be continued

Comment: `cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/26_numerics/random/cauchy_distribution' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/microblaze'
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/26_numerics/random/gamma_distribution/cons' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/microblaze/others'` To be continued

Comment: `cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/27_io/basic_streambuf/cons/wchar_t' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/tic6x' cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/27_io/basic_streambuf/overflow' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/spu'
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/27_io/basic_streambuf/sputbackc/char' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/spu/ea'` To be continued

Comment: `cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/27_io/basic_stringstream/requirements' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gfortran.dg'
cp: will not create hard link src/gcc.tmp/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/27_io/ios_base/callbacks' to directory src/gcc.tmp/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/x86_64/abi/callabi'
make: *** [src/gcc] Error 1` This is it, at last) I can't understand clearly what does that error mean.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that if you are using Windows 10 then you enrol into the preview builds and then you can get hold of the Windows Subsystem for Linux. I have been able to use it to download and build the riscv toolchain using the instructions provided at the riscv.org website.

Answer (score 0):

xpack-dev-tools has a package of a riscv gcc for several different operating systems.

See https://github.com/xpack-dev-tools/riscv-none-elf-gcc-xpack/

I'm currently looking into using this package with VS Code on a Windows PC to develop C/C++ programs that run on a VisionFive 2 RISC-V SBC. I'm curious as to whether I can have WINE on the SBC and compile Windows programs that will then run on the SBC under WINE.

I found this VS Code page, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools which has some links to compilers. See as well this package manager, MSYS at https://www.msys2.org/ which is mentioned in the Visual Studio Code documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56622710/1466970

What I've been doing is running Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on a Windows 11 PC on which I have installed the riscv gcc toolchain. I then cross compile applications that I can run on my VisionFive 2.

I've used this same toolchain with the GitHub source from StarFive, manufacturer of the VisionFive 2, to build two different versions of a Linux kernel on a Ubuntu session of WSL and then use the Raspberry Pi Imager application under Windows to create a bootable SD card. I've also used it to compile a device driver for a USB WiFi adapter that I then used on the VisionFive 2.